# /summon Command Help

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

What is wrong with this command? It says it has a problem with value separators, but i can't find it

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~10 {ShowArms:1,NoBasePlate:1,Pose:{LeftArm:[0f,0f0f],RightArm:[0f,0f,0f],Body:[0f,0f,0f],LeftLeg:[0f,0f,0f],RightLeg:[0f,0f,0f],Head:[0f,0f,0f]},ArmorItems:{id:diamond_boots,ench:[{id:protection,lvl:1000},{id:blast_protection,lvl:1000},{id:thorns,lvl:1000},{id:unbreaking,lvl:1000}]},{id:diamond_leggings,ench:[{id:protection,lvl:1000},{id:blast_protection,lvl:1000}, {id:thorns,lvl:1000},{id:unbreaking,lvl:1000}]}, {id:diamond_chestplate,ench:[{id:protection,lvl:1000},{id:blast_protection,lvl:1000},{id:thorns,lvl:1000},{id:unbreaking,lvl:1000}]},{id:diamond_helmet,ench:[{id:protection,lvl:1000},{id:blast_protection,lvl:1000},{id:thorns,lvl:1000},{id:unbreaking,lvl:1000}]}}
```

Comment: Now that I think about it, this probably wasn't the best choice of canonical question for "item data needs to be in a tag called `tag`".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The item format dictates that any tags that aren't the root `id`, `Damage`, `Count`, or `Slot`, must be placed within a single `tag` compound. Enchantments do not yet use name IDs within NBT data, so you must use numerical IDs for now. When this changes in the future, you will switch to name IDs.

The `ArmorItems` tag is a list, which surrounds its data (being compounds) in square brackets.

Without a `Count` tag specified, it will default to 0.

Fixed command:

```
/summon ArmorStand ~ ~ ~10 {ShowArms:1,NoBasePlate:1,Pose:{LeftArm:[0f,0f0f],RightArm:[0f,0f,0f],Body:[0f,0f,0f],LeftLeg:[0f,0f,0f],RightLeg:[0f,0f,0f],Head:[0f,0f,0f]},ArmorItems:[{id:"minecraft:diamond_boots",Count:1b,tag:{ench:[{id:0s,lvl:1000s},{id:3s,lvl:1000s},{id:7s,lvl:1000s},{id:34s,lvl:1000s}]}},{id:"minecraft:diamond_leggings",Count:1b,tag:{ench:[{id:0s,lvl:1000s},{id:3s,lvl:1000s},{id:7s,lvl:1000s},{id:34s,lvl:1000s}]}}, {id:"minecraft:diamond_chestplate",Count:1b,tag:{ench:[{id:0s,lvl:1000s},{id:3s,lvl:1000s},{id:7s,lvl:1000s},{id:34s,lvl:1000s}]}},{id:"minecraft:diamond_helmet",Count:1b,tag:{ench:[{id:0s,lvl:1000s},{id:3s,lvl:1000s},{id:7s,lvl:1000s},{id:34s,lvl:1000s}]}}]}
```